# Error com caractere AES_DECRYPT MySQL e Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Boa tarde galera. Alguém saberia me ajudar a encontrar esse erro?
Criei uma área de login no site, mas estou tento problema quando o usuário usa na sua senha o caractere exclamação "!". Exemplo de senha: 123456A!
Assim que ele tenta logar da um erro no MySql. Segue o código:

Login - Model

```
public function login($data)
    {
        $this->db->where('usuario', $data['usuario']);
        $this->db->where($this->db->escape($data['senha']), "CAST(AES_DECRYPT(senha,'".$this->config->item('encryption_key')."') AS CHAR(255))",FALSE);
        $this->db->where('status', '1');
        $query = $this->db->get('usuarios')->result();
        return $query;
    }
```

Error:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CAST(AES_DECRYPT(senha,'0ThearAOdAf9amHJ8mSi4Pc7adDvwUFq') AS CHAR(255)) AND `st' at line 4

SELECT * FROM `teste_usuarios` WHERE `usuario` = 'usuario1' AND '123456789!@' CAST(AES_DECRYPT(senha,'iz2GrBvs34UArNWxxUoELxoqEOlTTsA8') AS CHAR(255)) AND `status` = '1'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/novosite/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar. Agradeço.
Abraço a todos.

Comment: O método `$this->db->where()` geralmente espera como primeiro parâmetro o nome da coluna na tabela. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: Sua query não está sendo montada corretamente. Observe que falta a coluna senha: `... \`usuario\` = 'usuario1' AND '123456789!@' ...`.

Comment: Boa tarde @PauloImon obrigado pelo retorno. Então não sei o porquê não está motando corretamente. O engraçado é que só monta errado quando coloco o caractere exclamação "!" na senha.

Comment: Então, acredito que seja pelos parâmetros que está passando no método `where()` da Query Builder. Você poderia tentar assim: `$this->db->where('senha', $data['senha']);` e no seu Controller você decripta a `$data['senha']` antes de passar pro Model. Para senhas a própria doc do CodeIgniter recomenda utilizar a extensão [Password Hashing](https://php.net/password) do PHP no lugar da lib de criptografia: `Passwords must be hashed instead, and you should do that via PHP’s own Password Hashing extension.` Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Boa tarde @PauloImon Então, fiz como você e o lcssanches recomendaram usando password_hash e password_veriy e com isso deu certo. Tirei a verificação da senha do Model e joguei para o controle. Só uma diferença ali que você mencionou que não fiz foi no Model passar isso aqui: `$this->db->where('senha', $data['senha']);` no model apenas passei a verificação se o usuário existe e no controle descriptografo a senha. Acredito que é isso. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Boa noite @Saulo. Entendi. Que bom que deu certo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não faça o controle de senhas assim criptografando e para verificar descriptografando.

Em 99% dos casos você deve utilizar [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php) e [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-verify.php).

Funcionaria dessa forma:

```php
function do_login($user, $plain_password){
    $this->db->select('password');
    $this->db->where('user', $user);
    $user_obj = $this->db->get('users')->row;
    if(!$user_obj) return false;
    $hash_password = $user_obj->password;
    return password_verify($plain_password, $hash_password);
}

function create_login($user, $plain_password){
    $hash_password = password_hash($plain_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $this->db->set('user', $user);
    $this->db->set('password', $hash_password);
    $this->db->insert('users');
    return true;
}
```